# Unable to add the image using image asset in android studio

Tags: android-studio, here-api

[image]

**When I try to add the image it shows the error which doesn't allow me to go next or previous to add the image as shown in the picture above.Can anyone suggest a solution to solve this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to follow below instructions :

> ```
> 1)file->New->Folder
>  there are multiple options like
>       aidl folder
>       assets folder
>       jni folder
> 2) choose options assets folder
> 3) then there is option to change path of assets folder if you 
>     want to change then check otherwise left that checkbox of cahnge folder location
> 4) click on finish
> ```